# LXR initdb-mysql script in v2.0.0

Tags: linux-kernel, lxr

I am trying to install LXR tp parse my working folder of linux. In some of the tutorials on the web to set it up, they are trying to use the initdb-mysql script to initialize LXR's database in mysql. Well, I can not find this script in v2.0.0 but I can see it in older versions. Is that one still valid for use with v2.0.0? If not, what script I can use to setup the db for LXR v2.0.0? or if this whole DB thing was dropped how can I proceed?

on a side note: why linux projects always lack the proper documentation?!!!! I can see they have procedure for installing LXR on their own webiste and I believe it is outdated...why not update it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you're still looking for an answer, but here is one for the record.

Creating the DB is part of LXR initialization and is considered an internal step (i.e. not end-user visible). As such, it is allowed to change along the configuration process. This is why it is crucial to follow the procedure adapted to the LXR version.

LXR 2.x is configured with a configuration wizard (scripts/configure-lxr.pl) which takes care of generating the DB structure based on a template (templates/initdb/initdb-*-template.sql). These templates are not directly usable; they must be customized by the wizard to produce an initialization script custom.d/initdb.sh which you must manually launch after the wizard has finished its job.

The whole procedure for a simple case is shown on the [LXR site](http://lxr.sourceforge.net). From the home page, select the installation link for the version you use (note that the procedure for 1.x also applies to 2.x).

For complex cases, download and read the comprehensive user's manual from [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lxr/files/doc). Once again, select the manual adapted to the LXR version.

These manuals are not outdated since the LXR project has a rule to withhold release until documentation is ready.